# How to deal with composite products in WooCommerce?

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, woocommerce

The function `wc_get_product` below comes from the Wordpress plugin WooCommerce. Normally it is very easy to use and returns a regular object, but here I am trying to use it on a 'composite product', which makes it much trickier.

I call the function as follows:

```
$product = wc_get_product($productid);
var_dump($product);
```

And what that returns is the following object:

```
object(WC_Product_Composite)#11305 (23) {
  ["extended_data":"WC_Product_Composite":private]=>
  array(7) {
    ["add_to_cart_form_location"]=>
    string(7) "default"
    ["shop_price_calc"]=>
    string(7) "default"
  }
  ["composite_meta":"WC_Product_Composite":private]=>
  array(4) {
    [1477435352]=>
    array(19) {
      ["component_id"]=>
      string(10) "1477435352"
      ["query_type"]=>
      string(11) "product_ids"
      ["assigned_ids"]=>
      array(2) {
        [0]=>
        int(541)
        [1]=>
        int(588)
      }
   }
}
```

How can I work with the "assigned ids"? I didn't find anything relevant in [the documentation](https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/composite-products/) that would help me work with these `WC_Product_Composite` objects.

Comment: Googling "Woocommerce WC_Product_Composite" quickly leads here: https://docs.woocommerce.com/documentation/plugins/woocommerce/woocommerce-extensions/composite-products/, start by reading that. If you're still unsure, ask specifically how to do a specific thing in Woocommerce, don't generally ask "how to access private properties."

Comment: I can't see anything in those docs that helps me decompile a composite product, unfortunately.

Comment: To be clear, from researching this (with my limited understanding) I believe I can somehow access this object if I know where the class is and how the object was created. Hence I asked how to decompile this specific object, and gave a succinct description of what software I am using, described which functions I am using, and the restrictions associated with it, and tagged the question as 'woocommerce' and 'wordpress'.  Far from asking 'generally'. Again, any further help would be greatly appreciated.